# Writing javascript function from ruby string in hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I have ROR Helper that build some Javascript code.
In the helper I have Hash of options and variables that define this javascript code. 
One of them is string that holds JS function, the problem is it rendered as a string and not as function when using to_json.

How can I make it work?

Example:

In my helper I have this code:

```
h = {url: '/some/url', async: false}
h[success] = "function(result) {alert(result);}"

"<script type='text/javascript'> jQuery.ajax(#{h.to_json}); </script>"html_safe
```

This code will generates:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/some/url',
    async: false,
    success: "function(result) {alert(result);}"
  });
</script>
```

What I wont to to achieve is that code (without the ".." in success part):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/some/url',
    async: false,
    success: function(result) {alert(result);}
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Why yes, JSON is not JavaScript, it doesn't have a concept of *function*, that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a *string* out of `h` *hash* instead of using `to_json`; for example:

```
def js_code
  h = {url: '"/some/url"', async: false}
  h[:success] = "function(result) { alert(result); }"
  s = h.map { |k, v| "#{k}: #{v}" }.join(",")

  "<script type='text/javascript'> jQuery.ajax({#{s}}); </script>".html_safe
end
```

Notice that additional double quotes (`"`) were added to `'"/some/url"'` in order to keep them in the final string.

Output:

```
<script type='text/javascript'> jQuery.ajax({url: "/some/url",async: false, success: function(result) { alert(result); }}); </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to remove the surrounding quotes with a regular expression like this.

```
"<script type='text/javascript'> jQuery.ajax(#{h.to_json}); </script>".gsub(/"success":"(.*)"/, '"success":\1')
```

which gives

```
<script type='text/javascript'> jQuery.ajax({"url":"/some/url","async":false,"success":function(result) {alert(result);}}); </script>
```

Which is not complety what you want.
I would just build a string instead of using the json approach.

```
html = %Q{
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery.ajax({
      url: '#{h[:url]}',
      async: #{h[:async]},
      success: #{h[:success]}
    });
  </script>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do that using heredoc syntax and string interpolation:

```
def some_helper_method
  h = { url: '/some/url', async: false }
  <<-HTML
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      jQuery.ajax({
        url: '#{ h[:url] }',
        async: #{ h[:async] },
        success: function(result) {
          alert(result);
        }
      });
    </script>
  HTML
end
```